# How to make sql image clickable on display board

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make the fetched images on a sql database clickable.  They display fine but no-one can click them or download them and I'd like them to be able to.  The script is below.

```
<?php
include_once 'connect.php';
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Leaderboard");
?>
<?php
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
?>
<p>Leaderboard and guest photos as of October 20, 2020.  Our apologies to our prior guests.</p>
<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
<tr>
<td>Date</td>
<td>Photo</td>
<td>Team Name</td>
<td># of Players</td>
<td>Escape Room</td>
<td>Time</td>
<td>Success</td>
<td>Game Master</td>
</tr>
<?php

$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["date"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo "<img src='/teamphotos/".$row['photo']." ' width='250' height='200'>"; ?>.   </td>

<td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["players"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["room"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["time"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["win"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["master"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</table>
<?php
}
else{
echo "No result found";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is SQL image?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want that if the user left clicks the image, a download of that image starts. For that you only need to wrap an anchor tag `<a>` around the `<img>` with the attributes `src` and `download`.

```
<td><?php echo '<a href="/teamphotos/'.$row['photo'].'" download><img src="/teamphotos/'.$row['photo'].'" width="250" height="200"></a>'; ?></td>
```

This is related to HTML and not to PHP. Here you can read more about it:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_download_link.asp